# URL bar is white all the way across

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

When I type a URL in, my bar looks like this:

[image]

Why is this and how do I fix it? I'm running Chrome 29.0.1547.57 m

Comment: This is just how the new theme on Chrome is. I don't think you can change that. I have the same on both my Windows 7 and Windows 8 systems.

Comment: When you say that it's white all the way across, do you mean that you want it to autofill suggestions for what you're typing? I'm on the same version on Windows 7 x64 and I get suggestions as I type.

Comment: Yes it works just like it used to it's just that there's white there. Also, Darth, I'm using a custom theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [new Chrome Style](http://www.heise.de/ix/meldung/Chrome-29-verbessert-URL-Vorschlaege-1939452.html). You can **not** change this. *Except deinstall this version and install an older one ;)*

Comment: Huh, it's super ugly. Oh well, thanks for the answer.